# Java 8 stream - or condition

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

See this code:
(This is working code but I don't like to use 2 lines so looking for how can I make it better)

```
ItemDetails[] items = response.getDetailsList();
items = Arrays.stream(items).filter(x -> !x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("acl1")).toArray(ItemDetails[]::new);
items = Arrays.stream(items).filter(x -> !x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("acl2")).toArray(ItemDetails[]::new);
```

I could not figure how to use an `OR (|)` condition within `filter` to remove two specific elements from `List` since it would give me compile time error (in IDE) and I end up using two `filters` like above.
What could I be missing?

This is how I tried to use OR

```
items = Arrays.stream(items).filter(x -> !x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("acl1") ||
        x -> !x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("acl2")).toArray(ItemDetails[]::new);
```

=> IntelliJ would complain about this one (above)

```
items = Arrays.stream(items).filter(x -> !x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("acl1"") ||
        x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("acl2")).toArray(ItemDetails[]::new);
```

Does not work at runtime (it does not filter)

Entire code with commented code (which I tried) for reference

```
public static void mapTest () {

        AclDetailItem[] items = new AclDetailItem[3];

        AclDetailItem item1 = new AclDetailItem();
        item1.setAclName("acl1");

        AclDetailItem item2 = new AclDetailItem();
        item2.setAclName("acl2");

        AclDetailItem item3 = new AclDetailItem();
        item3.setAclName("acl3");

        items[0] = item1;
        items[1] = item2;
        items[2] = item3;

        System.out.println ("Before " + items.length);


        items = Arrays.stream(items).filter(x -> !x.getAclName().equalsIgnoreCase("acl1")).toArray(ItemDetails[]::new);
        items = Arrays.stream(items).filter(x -> !x.getAclName().equalsIgnoreCase("acl2")).toArray(ItemDetails[]::new);

        System.out.println ("After "  + items.length);
    }
```

Comment: What error? What did you try? That's kind of important.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is a poor question.

Comment: items = Arrays.stream(items).filter(x -> !x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("redirect") || x->!x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("success")).toArray(ItemDetails[]::new);

Comment: Conditional or is `||` possibly this is your issue?

Comment: @Rockoder Please edit that into the original question.

Comment: Remove your second `x->`...

Comment: From these two, which one is correct?        items = Arrays.stream(items).filter(x -> !x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(aclGuestRedirect) ||
                x -> !x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(aclGuestRedirect)).toArray(AclDetailsItem[]::new);


        items = Arrays.stream(items).filter(x -> !x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(aclGuestRedirect) ||
                x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(aclGuestRedirect)).toArray(AclDetailsItem[]::new);

Comment: Which one do you think is correct? You have a lambda expression as `x -> something`. Now `something` must return a boolean here. So `!x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("redirect")` returns a boolean, all good. And then `!x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("redirect") || !x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("success")` also does...

Comment: This is a failure of understanding that subsequent application of filters is equivalent to an **AND** combination instead of OR, but successfully pointing every reader into the wrong direction with explicitly asking for an OR combination. You don’t even need to combine the filters, if all you want, is to have a single Stream op: `ItemDetails[] items = Arrays.stream(response.getDetailsList()) .filter(x -> !x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("acl1")) .filter(x -> !x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("acl2")) .toArray(ItemDetails[]::new);`

Answer (score 25):

You should create multiple predicates for each condition and join it using or. I have added my below example:

```
public class MeTest {

    Predicate<Integer> con1 = i -> i==0;
    Predicate<Integer> con2 = i -> i==1;
    Predicate<Integer> con3 = i -> i==2;

    @Test
    public void testOr() {
        List<Integer> asdas = IntStream.range(1, 10).boxed().filter(con1.or(con2).or(con3)).collect(toList());
        System.out.println("asdas = " + asdas);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is usually my preferred method.  It also allows utility classes to contain the predicates for matching, which is super nice.

Answer (score 6):

The first one is incorrect as it has a `x ->` too much.
The second one does not filter as you constructed a condition that is always `true`. Just refine your condition in the `filter`-method and it will filter.

EDIT (as the question got detailed):
I still think, you have an error in your condition. You probably want to exclude both `acl1` and `acl2`. If so, your condition should rather look something like:

```
!(x.getAclName().equalsIgnoreCase("acl1") || x.getAclName().equalsIgnoreCase("acl2"))
// or if you prefer &&
!x.getAclName().equalsIgnoreCase("acl1") && !x.getAclName().equalsIgnoreCase("acl2")
// or if you prefer regular expressions/matches
!x.getAclName().matches("(?i)^acl[1|2]$")
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Can someone upvote my question if this can help others! Not sure why it is -1 when it is attracting valid comments from people.

Answer (score 1):

```
items = Arrays.stream(items).filter(
    x -> !x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("redirect")
    || x->!x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
    .toArray(ItemDetails[]::new);
```

Note the second `x->`. That's used to bind a variable at the start of a lambda. Putting it in the middle is invalid, and unnecessary since `x` already exists in the scope. Just remove that bit:

```
items = Arrays.stream(items).filter(x ->
    !x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("redirect")
    || !x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
    .toArray(ItemDetails[]::new);
```

Comment: Will test this answer and update. I think I have tried all possible permutations but it did not work. I tried many  variations and finally gave up to use solution I posted since I wanted to move to next task.

Comment: Update: my bad, I messed up on syntax. Now it compiles fine. Testing it.

Comment: If the question is valid, do please upvote guys! It screwed up my badge/rank

Comment: @Rockoder I'm trying to manipulate code on my phone, so my keyboard might have f'd the syntax somewhere. Just remove the second variable binding from the filter lambda.

Comment: Sorry, does not work on runtime. It does not filter. I am printing the length of array before filtering and after and they are same. the idea is to filter original array.

Comment: @Rockoder The validity of your condition is difficult for me to judge given I don't have sample data to use. I also don't have a Java IDE handy, so I can't actually test it. Your main problem was the double variable binding in the lambda. Whether or not your condition actually does what you want is arguably a separate issue.  Dumb question, but you know that filter removes elements for which the condition is false right? It "selects" true elements.

Comment: And what do you want to check against? `aclGuestRedirect` or `"redirect"`?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar question: how to use Java streams to filter a subset of objects that satisfy CONDITION_1 OR CONDITION_2. I figured out it would be to include both conditions in the filter.

```java
myListOfElms().stream()
  .filter(elm -> elm.condition1OK() || elm.condition2OK())
  .collect(toList());
```

Of course wrapping these conditions in a private method would make it look better. But that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Question is "filter out with certain condition from Male or Female with one line"
    with consumer implementation for printing
    Answer
    --------
    public class Emp{
         private String name;
         private int age;
         private String gender; with setter, getter Allargument constructor}
    
    public class MailFemaleFilter {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<Emp> empli=new ArrayList<Emp>();
            empli.add(new Emp("A",33,"m"));
            empli.add(new Emp("B",26,"m"));
            empli.add(new Emp("C",18,"m"));
            empli.add(new Emp("D",90,"m"));
            empli.add(new Emp("E",45,"m"));
            
            //female
            empli.add(new Emp("A1",7,"f"));
            empli.add(new Emp("B1",29,"f"));
            empli.add(new Emp("C1",70,"f"));
            empli.add(new Emp("D1",23,"f"));
            empli.add(new Emp("E1",39,"f"));
    //creation of predicate
    Predicate<Emp> agetest =  e-> e.getAge() > 30;
            Predicate<Emp> genderMtest =  m-> m.getGender().equals("m");
            Predicate<Emp> genderFtest =  mf-> mf.getGender().equals("f");
        List<Emp> FilteredEmp=empli.stream().filter(agetest.and((genderMtest).or(genderFtest)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());  
    
    //printing by consumer
    
     MyConsumer action = new MyConsumer();
            FilteredEmp.forEach(action);
                    
            
        }
    
    }
    //creation of consumer implementation 
    class MyConsumer implements Consumer<Emp>{
    
        public void accept(Emp t) {
            System.out.println("Consumer impl name of emp ::"+t.getName()+":: with respective gender ::"
                    +t.getGender());
        }
    }
```